# What is GLOBALPKG.RET1 used for?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to know what kind of parameter I should send in for RG1.  I am getting a SQL Error:

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_CONFIG'.

I have the following procedure in Oracle:

```
PROCEDURE        "PROC_CONFIG" (
  name        VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  in_value    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  RC1         IN OUT GLOBALPKG.RET1
  )

  IS
  value    VARCHAR2(255);
  option_id   NUMBER(10,0);
  count        NUMBER(10,0);
  flags        NUMBER(10,0);
  user_id      NUMBER(10,0);
  value_prev  VARCHAR2(255);
  option_name VARCHAR2(255);
  filter       VARCHAR2(255);
```

I only copied what I thought was important and where RC1 was used.

```
  BEGIN
  value := in_value;

  user_id:=ip_user();
  IF(user_id = 0) THEN
      RETURN ;
  END IF;

  filter := name;
  ip_build_filter(filter);

  IF(value is NULL) THEN
      OPEN RC1 FOR
      SELECT
          SUBSTR('000',0,4-length(TO_CHAR(d.option_id))) || TO_CHAR(d.option_id)
                  || '. ' || d.name  "Option",
    u.name  "User",
    NVL(v.value, '(not specified)')  "Value"
      FROM option_values v, option_defs d, users u
      WHERE (v.option_id = d.option_id)
          AND (v.user_id = u.user_id(+))
          AND d.name  LIKE proc_config.filter
          and BITAND(d.flags,15) <> 0;

      RETURN;

  END IF;
```

When I send the following statement from my company's c++ application, everything works fine and the procedure selects and shows all related data.

{call proc_config ('', '')};

Thanks to anyone who tries to understand this!

Comment: Is your procedure overloaded? If not, where is the third argument in your C++ call? How are you calling it when you get the error?

Comment: Currently, I am trying to call it from Oracle SQL Developer by using:   call PROC_CONFIG('minimum_password_length', 5);   Or with call PROC_CONFIG('', ''); This is where I am getting my error message.  My c++ program currently works for SQL server, but am trying to get it to work with Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example globalpkg.ret1 seems to be TYPE of REF CURSOR declared in  package specification of package named globalpkg. In order to call your procedure "PROC_CONFIG" you should pass IN OUT variable of this type to your procedure. The call will look in PL/SQL (you can try it in your Oracle SQL Developer) somehow like this:

```
DECLARE
   i_rc1 globalpkg.rec1;
BEGIN
   "PROC_CONFIG"('','',i_rc1);
END;
```